# Tabularray. Need a partial vertical line at the beginning of the table

Tags: line, tabularray, hline

I'm trying to format a table to have an empty space in the first two rows and first column. That means no vertical line at row{1}, but the other must have. Haven't figured out how to do that.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{multirow, array} % Opciones para trabajar con tablas

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[
    caption = {Title.},
    label = {tab:an-c-cortes},
    entry = {},
    ]{
        colspec = {Q[l,m,2cm]|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|Q|},
        rowhead = 1,
        row{1} = {font = \footnotesize\bfseries},
        row{2-Z} = {font = \footnotesize},
        rowsep = 0pt,
%       cell{2-Z}{1} = {c},
    }
    \cline{3-8}
    \SetCell[c=2]{c} & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Data 1 & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Data 2 & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Data 3 \\
    \hline
    \SetCell{c} A & B & Puntaje & C & Puntaje & D & E & F \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Table output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

It is not entirely clear if your table is simple table or long table. You write mess of both code. In MWE below I assume the first and that table isin `table` float with caption:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage{multirow, array} % Not used in this MWE   pciones para trabajar con tablas
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
%\usepackage{xcolor}          % Not used in this MWE
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}    % Not used in this MWE

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Title.}
  \label{tab:an-c-cortes}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1}={3-Z}{solid}, hline{2-Z}={solid},             % changed
             vline{1-2}={2-Z}{solid}, vline{3-Z}={solid},           % new
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c, wd=12mm] c} *{2}{Q[c, wd=2em]}},  % changed
             cell{1}{odd} = {c=2}{},                                % in first row are multi column cells
             row{1}   = {font = \footnotesize\bfseries},
             row{2-Z} = {font = \footnotesize},
             }
    &   &   Data 1  &   &   Data 2  &   &   Data 3  &   \\
A   & B &   Puntaje & C &   Puntaje & D &   E       & F \\
1   & 2 &   3       & 4 &   5       & 6 &   7       & 8 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a simple table. Shouldn't the caption be placed inside \begin{tblr}? It's my first time using this package, so I got the code out of a longtblr.

Regarding your previous response, thank you for providing the solution I was looking for!

Comment: @JJP, in spirit of `tabularray` package (as far as I know), no. For caption inside `tabularray` table are intended `longtblr` and `talltblr`.

Answer (score 2):

For information, here is a way to create that table with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Title.}
  \label{tab:an-c-cortes}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{c}}[hvlines,corners]
    &   & \Block{1-2}{Data 1} & & \Block{1-2}{Data 2} & & \Block{1-2}{Data 3} \\
A   & B & Puntaje & C & Puntaje & D & E & F \\
1   & 2 & 3       & 4 & 5       & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]